# LED strip power supply 12V 2A vs. 12V 25A

Tags: led-strip

I am using a white light LED strip in my 3D printer enclosure. And I would like to use the power supply of my 3D printer to power this LED strip.

The original power supply of the LED strip is 12V/2A
The power supply of the printer outputs 12V/25A

Can I use the power supply of the 3D printer to power this LED strip, or will it overheat the LEDs?

Thanks

Comment: > Can I use the power supply of the 3D printer to power this LED strip, 

Yes. 

12V is the "electrical pressure".   
25A is the electrical current that the supply **CAN** provide at that pressure.   

2A is the current that the load **WILL** take at that pressure.   
You then have 23A for use elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much!